# Float textbox inline with \section or \subsection title

Tags: sectioning, minipage, wrapfigure

I am creating a document that contains several text-boxes to serve as info-boxes for further information. I use the `boxedminipage` & `wrapfig` packages to achieve this: `boxedminipage` for a box with outline and the ability to change the style inside the box, and `wrapfig` to float the box either left or right of the main text. This all works as intended.

However, I am unhappy with the result when I include a textbox right at the start of a section or subsection. I would be very happy if I could move the box all the way up on the same level of the section title, but I expect the box to at least start on the same line as the main text, which it doesn't. See the screenshot below.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,boxedminipage,lipsum}
\begin{document}    
    \section{FOO}
    \subsection{Foo Bar Bas}    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{boxedminipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \fontsize{10}{10}
            \textbf{Lipsum lorem lippilip}\\\lipsum[66]
        \end{boxedminipage}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: floating wrong]

Desired result:

[image: floating right]

Note: changing the `wrapfig` option to `R` or `r` doesn't affect the outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a negative `\vspace*`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,boxedminipage,lipsum}
\begin{document}    
    \section{FOO}
    \subsection{Foo Bar Bas}    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}\vspace*{-2.5\baselineskip}
        \begin{boxedminipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \fontsize{10}{10}
            \textbf{Lipsum lorem lippilip}\\\lipsum[66]
        \end{boxedminipage}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

[image]